# Web service response is null, but SOAP message response is valid

Tags: soap, service, wsdl, jax-ws

I am writing a web service starting with writing the WSDL.  I have been generating server-side skeleton code using wsimport and then writing my own implementing class.  I'm running the web service on an Axis2 server.  When using soapUI, the SOAP messages coming to and from the service look fine, but when using a web service client, I'm getting null in the client-side stubs.  I've heard that this could be a namespace issue, but I see anything wrong.  Here is my copy of the WSDL.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:ns1="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://test.sa.lmco.com" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" targetNamespace="http://test.sa.lmco.com">


<!-- **************** -->
<!-- **   Types    ** -->
<!-- **************** -->
<wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://test.sa.lmco.com">
        <xs:element name="sayHello">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="s" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="sayHelloResponse">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>

        <xs:element name="getTaxonomyNode">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="taxonomyId" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"   type="xs:int" />
                    <xs:element name="nodeId"   type="xs:int" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>

        <xs:element name="getTaxonomyNodeResponse">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="resultNode"   type="ns:TaxonomyNode" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>

        <xs:element name="getChildren">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="taxonomyId"   minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xs:int" />
                    <xs:element name="parentNodeId" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xs:int" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>

        <xs:element name="getChildrenResponse">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="childNodes"   minOccurs="0"   maxOccurs="unbounded"   type="ns:TaxonomyNode" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>



        <xs:complexType name="TaxonomyNode">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="taxonomyId" type="xs:int" />
                <xs:element name="nodeId"     type="xs:int" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>


        <xs:complexType name="LCD">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="language" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="content"  type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="description"  type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>   

    </xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>

<!-- ***************** -->
<!-- **  Messages   ** -->
<!-- ***************** -->
<wsdl:message name="sayHelloRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:sayHello"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="sayHelloResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:sayHelloResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="getTaxonomyNodeRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:getTaxonomyNode" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getTaxonomyNodeResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:getTaxonomyNodeResponse" />
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="getChildrenRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:getChildren" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getChildrenResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:getChildrenResponse" />
</wsdl:message>

<!-- ******************* -->
<!-- **   PortTypes   ** -->
<!-- ******************* -->
<wsdl:portType name="HelloWSPortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="sayHello">
        <wsdl:input message="ns:sayHelloRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:sayHello"/>
        <wsdl:output message="ns:sayHelloResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:sayHelloResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="getTaxonomyNode">
        <wsdl:input  message="ns:getTaxonomyNodeRequest"  wsaw:Action="urn:getTaxonomyNode" />
        <wsdl:output message="ns:getTaxonomyNodeResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:getTaxonomyNodeResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="getChildren">
        <wsdl:input  message="ns:getChildrenRequest"  wsaw:Action="urn:getChildren" />
        <wsdl:output message="ns:getChildrenResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:getChildrenResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>

</wsdl:portType>


<!-- ****************** -->
<!-- ** Bindings     ** -->
<!-- ****************** -->
<wsdl:binding name="HelloWSServiceSoap11Binding" type="ns:HelloWSPortType">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="sayHello">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:sayHello" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="getTaxonomyNode">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:getTaxonomyNode" style="document" />
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="getChildren">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:getChildren" style="document" />
        <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>


</wsdl:binding>


<!-- **************** -->
<!-- ** Service    ** -->
<!-- **************** -->
<wsdl:service name="HelloWS">
    <wsdl:port name="HelloWSServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint" binding="ns:HelloWSServiceSoap11Binding">
        <soap:address location="http://162.16.129.25:9090/axis2/services/HelloWS"/>
    </wsdl:port>

</wsdl:service>
```

Comment: can you also post the SOAP request (from the client, not from SoapUI)? And, is the client on the same domain as the Web Service?

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of separate WSDL files.

If you specify WSDL separately in META-INF then AXIS2 passes arguments of the webservice as an OMElement.

I.e. if you have used other datatypes as arguments in service API and you have a WSDL in META-INF then while calling Service the parameters are OMElement not String / int or etc...

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with Soap web services, that is I am getting null response. I found the reason is I need to add appropriate Header fields in the request: Say for example - content-type, content-encoding, etc., depending on the service written. You better check with the one who has written the web services